# File not found. nginx

Tags: nginx, docker-compose

i want to run a small php application with docker and docker-compose. html files work successfully but when i access to php files i get File not found.

this is nginx/sites/default.conf

```
server {

    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;

    server_name localhost;
    root /var/www;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    location / {
         try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri /index.php =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass php-upstream;
        fastcgi_index index.php;

        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;

    }
}
```

this is docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'

services:
  php-fpm:
    build:
      context: ./docker/php-fpm

  nginx:
    build:
      context: ./docker/nginx
    volumes:
      - .:/var/www
      - ./docker/nginx/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
      - ./docker/nginx/sites/:/etc/nginx/sites-available
      - ./docker/nginx/conf.d/:/etc/nginx/conf.d
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    depends_on:
      - php-fpm
      - database

  database:
    build:
      context: ./docker/database
    environment:
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=mydb
      - MYSQL_USER=myuser
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=secret
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=docker
    volumes:
      - ./docker/database/data:/var/lib/mysql
```

> how can i solve this

Comment: You don't share your current directory with the php container so it doesn't see the file.

Comment: Oh yeaaah Thanks a lot :)))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per my comment the source files were not shared with the php container. Thus the php container would not find the file.